# Pass same SSRS parameter value to next reports to maintain the path

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a multivalued filter as a parameter on my reports. The values are the months of the years. The default value is the current month. The vaser can she the reports for each month by selection a month value from the filter.

There is also a text box in the report that shows the month value that which month has been selected as

[@Month.Label]

The problem is that now i need to maintain the navigation. From the main report there are links to the next reports. But when I click on the link to go to the other report the report shows the current month's report.
Is it possible that if i click on the link in the report the selected month value could passed to the next report instead of the current month value?

[Graphical Description of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YM4YQ.png)

Comment: What kind of links are there to the next reports? Are these subreports?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your have control over the client application then you probably want to expose the default value as a nullable parameter @ReportDate. This way you can pass in the optional value. The default will be used when no value is passed in. However, this will only work if the date filter applied outside of the report, otherwise, you will have to link to child reports as sub-reports to keep the value persistent between transitions.